# How can I set check interval for set autoread option in VIM

Tags: vim, vimrc, gvim

How can I set check interval for set autoread option in VIM? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

The `autoread` option does not have a timer. A reload is triggered when a shell command is launched or `checktime` is executed. Furthermore, vim does not have built-in timer functionality, so there's no simple way (meaning without plugins or ugly hacks) to call `checktime` every `n` seconds.

You can misuse `updatetime` and events like `CursorHold` to execute `checktime` when no key is pressed for the configured time. That's not exactly the solution, but it comes close.

```
autocmd CursorHold * checktime
```

Note that this autocommand only triggers in normal mode, but I would say that makes sense in this case. You don't want to auto reload while you are typing.